# Can't re-flag a comment after the answer is deleted and then undeleted

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, comment-flags, helpful-flags

An answer was posted, it was then down-voted and then the OP of the answer commented saying:

> Why Downvote ????

[image]

Thereafter the answer was deleted and my flag was helpful but not because the comment had been deleted but because the whole answer had been deleted. A short while later the answer was undeleted and lo and behold the comment was still there but now I can't flag it:

[image]

I don't believe this is at all worthy of consuming a mods time but other than this being fixed, can anything else be done by myself in the meantime?

Comment: In the meantime? Why not leave it for someone else to flag? (I agree that the result is kinda buggy, but that's not a reason for you having to do anything else)

Comment: @yivi alrighty, understood. I was more trying to see if there was anything else that *could* be done by myself in this scenario.

Comment: I just mean I don't think spending too much energy on these things is very useful. This is small enough as to merit a _"can't fix, let someone else deal with it"_ attitude, IMO. (At least until they fix the bug, if they do consider it a bug and fix it)

Comment: Did you ever flagged the comment?

Comment: @Braiam yes. As the second image shows.

Comment: I too often wondered the same thing, by that also happening to me. \**Shrugs\**.

Answer (score 18):

It's true, comment flags are marked helpful when the post they're under is deleted. It doesn't actually delete the comment. The comment remains visible for 10k+ users. If the post is undeleted the comment is visible.

This is painful. As the flagged comment is not dealt with and mods don't see it.

It's a bug really, I suspect that extends from comments being treated as "second class citizens" and less effort being put their way. For instance, mods cannot give a reason when marking a flag as helpful or declining. The comment either is deleted or not deleted.

So the issues are:

1. The comment is not deleted.

   *If* you see this, please reflag the comment, explaining why you're reflagging it.
2. Mods don't see the comment flag if the post is deleted, as the flag is marked helpful.

   If it's an issue that you need a mod to see *and* you notice, again reflag and explain why.
3. Users may be issued rude/unkind flags on comments that didn't warrant those flags.

   Too many rude/unkind flags will trigger a mod flag and mods will investigate the user's behaviour. All flagged comments can be seen. Often there will be comments that are flagged, marked as helpful and not deleted. The mod has to actively review the flagged comments before taking any disciplinary action, such as contacting the user. The human eyes help to prevent an abuse of the system. This is reassuring, as there's potential for abuse of flagging comments, deleting the post and undeleting it.

   If you believe someone is abusing this, please raise a custom mod flag on the post.

Comment: When you say case #2: "Mods don't see the comment," do you mean like an aged away flag? Otherwise I don't really get how we could know the difference between the first and second cases, but maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: When the post is deleted the comment flag is marked as helpful, so the flag leaves our queues. @DavyM

Comment: This is also sort of related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319111/310756 Hoping to get comment flagging up to date with community expectations.

Answer (score -14):

This is a clashing from assumptions made around comments, flags and deletion:

- Every flag on a comment that gets deleted is marked as helpful.
- Every comment on an deleted answer is marked as deleted.
- The only way to mark a comment flag as helpful is via deletion.

I rest my case.

Comment: While this answer is true from a technical perspective, it clashes from how I would expect the system to work in the above case. Don't take my downvote personally